# Exception during Hadoop reduce phase: Data Corruption in map output. Incorrect fileSize 0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a modified version of a basic WordCount job written in Java. The original version runs perfectly, however when I try to use a custom output key (WritableComparable implementation) for the reducer I get the following error:

`java.io.IOException: Data Corruption in map output. Incorrect fileSize 0`

The custom output key is to allow further sorting based on the number of occurrences rather than the alphabetical order of the words (not implemented yet).

My source files:

```
public class WordCount implements Tool {

private Configuration config;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    ToolRunner.run(conf, new WordCount(), otherArgs);
}

public int run(String[] otherArgs) throws Exception {

    if (otherArgs.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("Specify output folder in mtukuacs/output");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    Job job = new Job(config);
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(WordKey.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("/app/poc/SampleData/mtukacs/input/"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/app/poc/SampleData/mtukacs/output/" + otherArgs[0]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    return 0;
}

@Override
public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
    config = conf;
}

@Override
public Configuration getConf() {
    return config;
}

public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, WordKey, IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    private WordKey wordKey = new WordKey();

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        wordKey.set(key, result);
        context.write(wordKey, result);
    }
}

public class WordKey implements WritableComparable<WordKey> {

    private Text keyText;
    private IntWritable keyValue;

    public WordKey() {
        keyText = new Text();
        keyValue = new IntWritable();
    }

    public void set(Text kt, IntWritable kv) {
        keyText = kt;
        keyValue = kv;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput output) throws IOException {
        keyText.write(output);
        keyValue.write(output);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput input) throws IOException {
        keyText.readFields(input);
        keyValue.readFields(input);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(WordKey wordKey) {
        return keyValue.compareTo(wordKey.keyValue);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return keyText.hashCode() * 163 + keyValue.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof WordKey) {
            WordKey wordKey = (WordKey) object;
            return keyText.equals(wordKey.keyText) && keyValue.equals(wordKey.keyValue);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return keyText.toString();
    }
}
```